# How to write a java class to be accessed in liferay theme?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, velocity, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I have a Scenario where I have a java class written in JSP and its members are used in that JSP itself.

The JSP is part of a liferay portlet.

Now, I need to write that class for the velocity template in liferay theme so that I can access it in navigation.vm file.

Following is a dummy snippet -

**xyz.jsp (part)**

```
<body>
<%
final class DummyABC {
public String method1() {

}
public String method2() {

}
public String method3() {

}

}
%>
</body>
```

I need to access this class in my navigation.vm file.

Please help me through it.

Comment: Try putting instance of your class in VelocityContext

Comment: I need to write this class somewhere. Where should I write it? I do not have the class written anywhere to get the instance.

Comment: Put that class in java project, create jar file having that class file and place jar under tomcat/lib/ext.

Comment: thanks Pankaj.
Can you also tell me how to use StringTokenizer in vm file?

Answer (score 0):

You can write new java class and create a object in init.vm file so that navigation.vm file can access this variable

Comment: Sravan, can you tell me the procedure for the same?