# Extend ServicePreAction class and add attribute under the key WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-velocity

I need to add some custom velocity variables in liferay 6.0.6 running on tomcat 6. Please tell me a way to do it.

I read it in a blog that we need to extend ServicePreAction class and add attribute under the key `WebKeys.VM_VARIABLES`.
But I am not able to achieve it. Please help me with this and correct me if I am going the wrong way.

Please refer the following question for my exact requirement.
- [How to access custom java class in theme.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24571706/how-to-write-a-java-class-to-be-accessed-in-liferay-theme)

Comment: This might help you http://www.opensourceforlife.com/2012/06/custom-velocity-variable-in-liferay-61.html

Comment: @LuckyBoy It would be great to have some summary (or short steps) from the link and the link as a reference in the answer. Thanks